# I want to deploy a nexjts and a wordpress site on ngixn ubontu 20.04 vps

Tags: nginx, subdirectory

I want to deploy two website on nienx One is nexjts and one wordpress I already deployed the nextjs website and it is showing on 'whitepanda.io' now i want that when user goes on this 'whitepanda.io/blogs' then the wordpress site will show up this is my config of 'etc/nginx/sites-available/whitepanda' -

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name whitepanda.io; 
      gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_min_length 256;

    location /_next/static/ {
                alias /var/www/whitepanda/.next/static/;
                expires 365d;
                access_log off;
        }

    location / {
                proxy_pass http://153.49.42.243.202:3000; 
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


#nEW 

location /blogs {
        alias /var/www/wordpress/;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blogs/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

Note I have two folders on "var/www/" one is "whitepanda" and other one is "wordpress"

I want that when a user goes 'whitepana.io' it will show the nextjs website and 'whitepanda.io/blogs' will show the wordpress site but whitepada.io is showing the main site whenever i go to 'whitepanda.io/blogs' it's giviing me 404 not found error.